# How do I save a contact to a specific iCloud account?

Tags: macos, icloud, contacts.app

I have multiple account sources for my Contacts (family iCloud, personal iCloud, Exchange, etc.) When I create a new contact, how do I specify what account I want it saved to? Right now, Contacts just saves it to the default account.

I'm on the latest Yosemite.

Comment: what is the default icloud account ?

Comment: I can't answer for yosemite, but in iOS it's buried in the settings, and not quick easy to change on the fly.  Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calenders > (Contacts Section) Default Account.   The same problem exists with Calender items, which is where I personally have the problem. All my contacts are saved in one group although I do have 2 contract groups iCloud and Exchange, but calender-wise I have 3 calenders where I need to be able to choose which it saves to....however, to do so I must change the default Calendar in settings.  It's a real pain and I've sent apple feedback.

Comment: @Tyson: It's probably the same for MacOSX since I don't see any way of selecting it. Buscar: The default iCloud account is set to my family iCloud account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you cannot change it on the fly on a per entry basis.  You have to set the default account in the preferences for contacts.app. However, when in Contacts, and you have a card open (perhaps the one you JUST made), pressing the OPTION key will highlight all the groups on the left side of the app that include this card.  When you have your list of cards showing on the right with the accounts or groups showing on the left, you can simply drag that entry to the group or account of your choosing. This is the only method I'm aware of.